# Showing maximum value of an object in an array when it as two max values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have an array from the api response and its objects.I need to find the value which has maximum total and I have display it I'm unable to solve it , when  there are two max values of the total.Is there any solution?

```
myArray[
{time: "2018-12-02", total: 25, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-13-02", total: 25, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-14-02", total: 35, percentage: 25, averageTime: 25},
{time: "2018-16-02", total: 65, percentage: 60, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-17-02", total: 40, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-18-02", total: 65, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-18-02", total: 35, percentage: 23, averageTime: 20}
];
```

I tried reduce function  like this:

```
var data =[];
data.reduce((max, p) => p.total > max ? p.total : max, data[0].total);
```

Comment: Can you explain it please?

Comment: What do you mean by 'when there are two max values of the total'?

Comment: when ther are two same values of object 'total' .

Comment: What do you want to display when there are two maximums? Both or either one or the earlier one or the later one? What if there are three, four? Or do you just need the max total value?

Comment: I need to display the time of when two objects has same highest 'total' value.

Comment: So in case multiple objects have the same 'maximum' value you need to return the time of all of them?

Comment: Yes @CataJohn.Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

#### Idea:

- Create a hashMap with `total` as keys and a variable to hold max value.
- Check if the key exists and if not, initialize it to an array.
- Push current object in this array.
- Fetch the array with the key as `max` and you will get all the values with max total.

Now that you have entire object, you can iterate and display any necessary values.

```js
var myArray = [{time: "2018-12-02", total: 25, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-13-02", total: 25, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-14-02", total: 35, percentage: 25, averageTime: 25},
{time: "2018-16-02", total: 65, percentage: 60, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-17-02", total: 40, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-18-02", total: 65, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-18-02", total: 35, percentage: 23, averageTime: 20}]

var max = 0;
var hashMap = myArray.reduce((acc, p) => {
  max = Math.max(max, p.total);
  acc[p.total] = acc[p.total] || [];
  acc[p.total].push(p);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(hashMap[max]);
```

#### With only time value

```js
var myArray = [{time: "2018-12-02", total: 25, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-13-02", total: 25, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-14-02", total: 35, percentage: 25, averageTime: 25},
{time: "2018-16-02", total: 65, percentage: 60, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-17-02", total: 40, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-18-02", total: 65, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-18-02", total: 35, percentage: 23, averageTime: 20}]

var max = 0;
var hashMap = myArray.reduce((acc, p) => {
  max = Math.max(max, p.total);
  acc[p.total] = acc[p.total] || [];
  acc[p.total].push(p.time);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(hashMap[max]);
```

Comment: Instead of getting the full object,Can you help to get the 'time' alone?

Comment: Kindly check the update. Though I prefer getting entire object. This way, its more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Math.max along with `spread` and `array.prototype.map`:

```js
var myArray = [
{time: "2018-12-02", total: 25, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-13-02", total: 25, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-14-02", total: 35, percentage: 25, averageTime: 25},
{time: "2018-16-02", total: 65, percentage: 60, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-17-02", total: 40, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-18-02", total: 65, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-18-02", total: 35, percentage: 23, averageTime: 20}
];

var max = Math.max(...myArray.map(e => e.total));

console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the maximum 'total' value in the array and then find all the elements of the array with that maximum value.

```js
var myArray = [
{time: "2018-12-02", total: 25, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-13-02", total: 25, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-14-02", total: 35, percentage: 25, averageTime: 25},
{time: "2018-16-02", total: 65, percentage: 60, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-17-02", total: 40, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-18-02", total: 65, percentage: 20, averageTime: 20},
{time: "2018-18-02", total: 35, percentage: 23, averageTime: 20}
];

var max = Math.max(...myArray.map(e => e.total));
var time = myArray.filter(item => item.total == max);

console.log(time);
```

Comment: You are looping twice. You can achieve this in same loop. Feel free to refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

```
function getMaxValue(myArray) {
    var totals = myArray.map(x => x.total);
    var max = filter(x => x == Math.max(totals));
    return max.length == 1 ? max[0] : 'unable to solve it';
}
```